# uploaded data is not visible in solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr4.7. I have created a new core by copying "collection1(default example provided by solr)" to different name say "wiki" and updated core.properties with new name. Hence new core is visible at solr admin panel.

After starting solr, I am trying to import the data to new core like below.

**$ java -jar post.jar ../../../enwiki-20150602-pages-articles1.xml -Durl='http://localhost:8983/solr/#/wiki/update'**

```
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file enwiki-20150602-pages-articles1.xml
SimplePostTool: WARNING: No files or directories matching -Durl=http:/localhost:8983/solr/#/wiki/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
Time spent: 0:00:03.671
```

I also tried

**$ java -jar post.jar ../../../enwiki-20150602-pages-articles1.xml**

But still while querying at solr admin panel I am not getting any data.So my question is if data has been indexed then why I can't see it. Where exactly I am doing wrong.

Comment: try to search for q=*:* and check if your updates are been reflected...

Comment: Already tried. But still not getting.

Comment: ok so that means the data is not been indexed....You need to check for the new core whether its been updated properly or not...

Comment: you said when you search with q=*:* and get nothing in the result that indicates it didn't indexed the data in the core you are searching...so updates are not happening the right core...

Comment: I know it sir.. My concern is why index has not been modified? There are only two cores. I have checked both.

Comment: you need to check in logs if you are getting any exception while indexing...or when you index it from web interface(provided by solr) does it confirm that indexing has been successfully...? it would better if you share the schema.xml

Comment: ok.. i will check for schema.xml. But I am using the default one.

Comment: I don't think you need the # in the URL.

Comment: You're posting to a "url" that has a local anchor. That's just read by the browser and is never transmitted to the server - it's just part of the admin interface for Solr. The URL is usually something like `http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/update`. You'll also have to issue a commit after a document has been added. Be sure to set up Solr logging if you're having issues to see that a request makes it to your server at all.

Comment: @all- i understand that the upload url was not proper. Also the scheme.xml must be updated as per my requirement.Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this has been resolved.

I had the exact same problem. You need to specify the path/location of where your file to be ingested is located.

*C:\test-solr>java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/testdemo/update -Dtype=text/csv -jar C:/test-solr/exampledocs/post.jar "C:\test-solr\exampledocs\ingestMeFile.csv"*